# Dungeon generator in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/AAdonaac/20150903/252889/Procedural_Dungeon_Generation_Algorithm.php

Im trying to do something like the link in jquery, but I have some troubles making it happen.

1) I create 10(x) different rectangles and place them in the middle of the canvas all mixed up upon each other - no problem

2) Separate rooms, let each room find a empty place in canvas - big problem

Plan 1: I compare two rooms, and if they touch each other then move one of them the shortest way to the edge of the other. But what if there already is a room there? Then I just got two new rooms touching each other...

Plan 2: Make an array of empty/occupied spots and move each room to an empty place. But how do I know which direction to move, so all rooms is placed around the center?

Plz help!

Trial code:

```
<canvas id="cnvs" width="500" height="500" style="background-color: #333;"></canvas>

var rooms = [],
  gw = 25, //grid width
  gh = 25; //grid height

//Room
function Room(x,y,w,h){
  this.x = x; this.y = y;
  this.w = w; this.h = h;
  };

//Setup
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  var w = Math.floor(2+Math.random()*3),
    h = Math.floor(2+Math.random()*3),
    x = Math.floor(gw/2)-Math.floor(w/2),
    y = Math.floor(gh/2)-Math.floor(h/2),
    room = new Room(x,y,w,h);
  rooms.push(room);
  };

//Draw in canvas
var ctx = $("#cnvs")[0].getContext("2d"),
  sz = 20;
ctx.lineWidth = "2";
ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';

for(var i=0; i<rooms.length; i++){
  ctx.rect(rooms[i].x*sz,rooms[i].y*sz,rooms[i].w*sz,rooms[i].h*sz);
  ctx.stroke();
  };
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working? Where is the problem?

Comment: Step 1 works, but Im very confused about how to do step 2 (Separate rooms). How do I separate the rooms like the link, so no room covers another room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is better:

```js
//global variables
var rooms = [],
 gw = 35, //grid width
 gh = 35; //grid height

//Room
Room = function(){
 var w = Math.floor(2+Math.random()*4),
  h = Math.floor(2+Math.random()*4),
  x = Math.floor(gw/3+Math.random()*gw/3)-Math.floor(w/2),
  y = Math.floor(gh/3+Math.random()*gw/3)-Math.floor(h/2),
  grid = [];

 //create grid with -1
 grid = [];
 for(var i=0; i<gh; i++){
  grid.push([]);
  for(var j=0; j<gw; j++) grid[grid.length-1].push(-1);
  };

 //Fill grid with distances
 this.gridDistance = function(x1,y1,c){
  if(grid[y1][x1]==-1 || grid[y1][x1]>c){
   grid[y1][x1] = c;
   if(x1>0) this.gridDistance(x1-1, y1, c+1);
   if(x1<gw-1) this.gridDistance(x1+1, y1, c+1);
   if(y1>0) this.gridDistance(x1, y1-1, c+1);
   if(y1<gh-1) this.gridDistance(x1, y1+1, c+1);
   };
  return;
  };
 this.gridDistance(x,y,0);

 //block rooms and rooms border
 for(var i=0; i<rooms.length; i++){
  var x1 = rooms[i].x, y1 = rooms[i].y, w1 = rooms[i].w, h1 = rooms[i].h;
  if(x1+w1<gw) w1 = w1+1;
  if(x1>0){ x1 = x1-1; w1 = w1+1; };
  if(y1+h1<gh) h1 = h1+1;
  if(y1>0){ y1 = y1-1; h1 = h1+1; };
  for(var j=0;j<h1; j++){
   for(var k=0;k<w1; k++){
    grid[y1+j][x1+k] = -1;
    };
   };
  };

 //block spaces where room cant fit
 for(var i=0; i<grid.length; i++){
  for(var j=0;j<grid[i].length; j++){
   var tmp = false;
   if( i+h>=gh ) tmp = true;
   else if( j+w>=gw ) tmp = true;
   else {
    for(var k=i; k<i+h; k++){
     for(var l=j;l<j+w; l++){
      if( grid[k][l]<0 ) tmp = true;
      };
     };
    };
   if(tmp) grid[i][j] = -1;
   };
  };

 //find shortest distance to fitable space
 var x1=0, y1=0, c=-1;
 for(var i=0; i<grid.length; i++){
  for(var j=0;j<grid[i].length; j++){
   if(grid[i][j]>=0 && (c==-1 || grid[i][j]<c) ){
    c = grid[i][j];
    x1= j;
    y1 = i;
    };
   };
  };
 
 this.gridDistance = undefined;

 this.x = x1; this.y = y1;
 this.w = w; this.h = h;
 };

//Setup
for(var i=0; i<25; i++){
 var room = new Room();
 rooms.push(room);
 };

$('body').append('ok');

//Draw in canvas
var ctx = $("#cnvs")[0].getContext("2d"),
 sz = 20;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = '1';
ctx.strokeStyle = '#666';
for(var i=0; i<gh; i++){ ctx.moveTo(0,i*sz); ctx.lineTo(gw*sz,i*sz); };
for(var i=0; i<gw; i++){ ctx.moveTo(i*sz,0); ctx.lineTo(i*sz,gh*sz); };
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = "2";
ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
for(var i=0; i<rooms.length; i++){ ctx.rect(rooms[i].x*sz,rooms[i].y*sz,rooms[i].w*sz,rooms[i].h*sz); ctx.stroke(); };
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I made step 2 work. I think it could be more elegant, so feel free to make it smarter.

```js
var rooms = [],
  grid = [],
  gw = 25, //grid width
  gh = 25; //grid height

//Room
Room = function(x,y,w,h){
  this.x = x; this.y = y;
  this.w = w; this.h = h;
  };

//functions
refreshGrid = function(){
  for(var i=0; i<grid.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<grid[i].length; j++) grid[i][j] = -1;
    };
  return;
  };

roomDistance = function(x,y,c){
  if(grid[y][x]==-1 || grid[y][x]>c){
    grid[y][x] = c;
    if(x>0) roomDistance(x-1, y, c+1);
    if(x<gw-1) roomDistance(x+1, y, c+1);
    if(y>0) roomDistance(x, y-1, c+1);
    if(y<gh-1) roomDistance(x, y+1, c+1);
    };
  return;
  };

roomFit = function(x,y,w,h){
  var tmp = true;
  if( x+w>=gw ) tmp = false;
    else if( y+h>=gh ) tmp = false;
      else {
        for(var i=y; i<y+h; i++){
          for(var j=x;j<x+w; j++){
            if( grid[i][j]<0 ) tmp = false;
            };
          };
  return tmp;
  };

blockSpaces = function(w,h){
  for(var i=0; i<rooms.length; i++){
    var rx = rooms[i].x,
      ry = rooms[i].y,
      rw = rooms[i].w,
      rh = rooms[i].h;
    if(rx+rw<gw) rw = rw+1;
    if(rx>0){ rx = rx-1; rw = rw+1; };
    if(ry+rh<gh) rh = rh+1;
    if(ry>0){ ry = ry-1; rh = rh+1; };
    for(var j=0;j<rh; j++){
      for(var k=0;k<rw; k++){
        grid[ry+j][rx+k] = -1;
        };
      };
    };
  for(var i=0; i<grid.length; i++){
    for(var j=0;j<grid[i].length; j++){
      if( roomFit(j,i,w,h)==false ) grid[i][j] = -1;
      };
    };
  };

findPlace = function(room){
  var x=0, y=0, c=-1;
  for(var i=0; i<grid.length; i++){
    for(var j=0;j<grid[i].length; j++){
      if(grid[i][j]>=0 && (c==-1 || grid[i][j]<c) ){
        c = grid[i][j];
        x= j;
        y = i;
        };
      };
    };
  room.x = x;
  room.y = y;
  };

//Setup
for(var i=0; i<gh; i++){
  var arr = [];
  for(var j=0; j<gw; j++) arr.push(0);
  grid.push(arr);
  };

for(var i=0; i<15; i++){
  var w = Math.floor(2+Math.random()*3),
    h = Math.floor(2+Math.random()*3),
    x = Math.floor(gw/2)-Math.floor(w/2),
    y = Math.floor(gh/2)-Math.floor(h/2);
  refreshGrid();
  roomDistance(x,y,0);
  blockSpaces(w,h);
  var room = new Room(x,y,w,h);
  findPlace(room);
  rooms.push(room);
  };

//Draw in canvas
var ctx = $("#cnvs")[0].getContext("2d"),
  sz = 20;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = '1';
ctx.strokeStyle = '#666';
for(var i=0; i<gh; i++){ ctx.moveTo(0,i*sz); ctx.lineTo(gw*sz,i*sz); };
for(var i=0; i<gw; i++){ ctx.moveTo(i*sz,0); ctx.lineTo(i*sz,gh*sz); };
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = "2";
ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
for(var i=0; i<rooms.length; i++){ ctx.rect(rooms[i].x*sz,rooms[i].y*sz,rooms[i].w*sz,rooms[i].h*sz); ctx.stroke(); };
```

```html
<canvas id="cnvs" width="500" height="500" style="background-color: #333;"></canvas>
```